# Why is contains ctble dense $A \subset X$ $\iff$ $\exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ s.t. at least one $x_i$ in every non-empty open set of $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is contains countable dense $A \subset X$ $\iff$ $\exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ s.t. at least one $x_i$ in every non-empty open set of $X$?

Because this is the def. given by wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space

---

If $X$ is a topological space (not necessarily infinite), then how can it contain an infinite amount of $x_i$s? And how is it countable then (countably infinite? What does just countable mean anyways?)?

Comment: Countable = Finite or Countable infinity. Nobody said the $x_n$'s must be different.

Comment: There can be $x_i=x_j$ for some $i\neq j$, so the set doesn't have to be necessarily infinite

Comment: "$X$' countable dense" makes no sense. You meant "$X$ has a countable dense subset".

Comment: @Adam But then why does one want to take the infinite sequence anyways? Is it a short hand for "take all the elements"?

Comment: @mavavilj taking an infinite sequence of (different) numbers from a set is the same as taking a countable subset from this set.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is countable it is itself a dense subset, trivially. If $X$ is finite, it's considered separable, because it has a dense subset that is **at most** countable.
Or if you prefer the slightly non-standard Wikipedia sequential way, if $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_N\}$ use the repeating sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N, x_1 \ldots$ where each element is mentioned multiple times, which is perfectly allowed, as the definition of a sequence does not say that $n \neq m$ implies $x_n \neq x_m$.

Usually, though, a subset $D$ of $X$ is called *dense* iff $\overline{D} = X$ and $X$ is called separable iff it has a dense subset that is at most countable (so finite or size $\aleph_0$).

Comment: What does "at most countable" mean?

Comment: @mavavilj It means the set is countable or finite. In here we mean that the set is countable when there exists a bijection from it to natural numbers. Note that some people instead of "at most countable" say just "countable", the definitions can differ